# VScode can't definition global variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I have the definition of the global variable "main" that I created in another file?

```
var main = {
structure: {}
}
```

I tried to add / * global main * /

[no_definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juulh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add global definitions. Just initialize your JS project by creating jsconfig.json, with the following content

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5"
    }
}
```

and restart editor, or use Ctrl+Shift+P -> Reload JavaScript Project.

[image: Result]